# How to hide a particular row from datalist in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net

In my project i have request page that contain a datalist with four templates Image(profilepic),Label(firstname), and Button1(accept), button2(deny) and a hidden field that contains the address of requester 
And written the code
 protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            HiddenField hd = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            string str = hd.Value;
            SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Update requests set frnshpstatus='Y' where Email='" + Session["UserName"] + "' And frnemail='" + str + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Deny")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            HiddenField hd = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            string str = hd.Value;
            SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Update requests set frnshpstatus='N' where Email='" + Session["UserName"] + "' And frnemail='" + str + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

On clicking on accept button the frnshpstatus in request table in Updated as 'Y' but it is still showing the accepted or deny requests in datalist.
I want them  to remove only from datalist but keep the record of requests in database.
Answer in asp.net using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right in thinking you want the row completely removed from the datalist after clicking either accept or reject? If that's the case just add a where clause to your query that populates the datalist

```
where frnshpstatus is null
```

or whatever the default value is if not null. Then after you have completed the accept/reject process at the end of your ItemCommand event handler you'll need to manually databind the datalist again

```
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Bind The DataList Again in "DataList1_ItemCommand" and write following Code in "DataList1_ItemDataBound" event.I am assuming that you are having "frnshpstatus" in DataSource which you are binding to DataList...

```
void  DataList1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {

     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
           DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);        
           string frnshpstatus= drv.Row["frnshpstatus"].ToString(); 
           if(frnshpstatus="Y")
           {
             // Retrieve the Button control in the current DataListItem.
             Button Button1  = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Button1");
             Button Button2  = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Button2");
             Button1.Visible=False;
             Button2.Visible=False;

             //You Can Also Hide Row but for that you need to set it an ID and set it attribute "runat=server" 

             HtmlTableRow row=(HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("trId");
             row.Visible=False;   
           }                        

     }

  }
```

Comment: It is giving exception  "Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Column 'frnshpstatus' does not belong to table DefaultView.

Source Error: 


Line 83:      {
Line 84:            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);        
Line 85:            string frnshpstatus= drv.Row["frnshpstatus"].ToString(); 
Line 86:            if(frnshpstatus=="Y")
Line 87:            {
"

Comment: I ahve already mentioned that "frnshpstatus" needs to be there in Datasource,you need to add "frnshpstatus" column in Datasource which you are binding...